# How to change the notification icon in home activity as soon as a push notification arrives in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm using push notification in my app ,i need to change the notification icon in my home activity as soon as the notification arrives.can we use interface inside firebase service for this purpose.

Comment: you can use a BroadcastReceiver to notify your activity about something from service.

Answer (score 1):

you can use custom receiver firebase Clude message

in your manifast

```
      <service
        android:name=".ReciverClass.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

And Your Reciver

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
 */
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

    sendNotification(notification, data);
}

private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage.Notification notification, Map<String, String> data) {
    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel_id")
            .setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
            .setContentText(notification.getBody())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentInfo(notification.getTitle())
            .setLargeIcon(icon)
            .setColor(Color.RED)
            .setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 300)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    try {
        String picture_url = data.get("picture_url");
        if (picture_url != null && !"".equals(picture_url)) {
            URL url = new URL(picture_url);
            Bitmap bigPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            notificationBuilder.setStyle(
                    new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bigPicture).setSummaryText(notification.getBody())
            );
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Notification Channel is required for Android O and above
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                "channel_id", "channel_name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        );
        channel.setDescription("channel description");
        channel.setShowBadge(true);
        channel.canShowBadge();
        channel.enableLights(true);
        channel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500});
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}}
```

good luck

Comment: this is retrieving msg from the push notification right, i need to execute an action when msg received in background (changing notification icon).

Answer (score 0):

You can use BroadcastReceiver for this.
send broadcast when you receive new notification in onMessageReceived method of firebase messaging service:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setAction("com.package.notification");
 sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Then create broadcast receiver in HomeActivity:

```
 BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           //your code to change icon
        }
    };
```

and register receiver in onCreate and unRegister in onDestroy method of HomeActivity:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
 filter.addAction("com.package.notification");
 registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, filter);

      try {
            if (mHandleMessageReceiver != null) {
                unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```